# my topic 'scan' was change to 'base_scan'

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i can successfully run the command

```
roslaunch rplidar_ros rplidar.launch
```

then i found i cannot found the topic `scan` created by `rplidar_node`,but a topic named `base_scan` created by `rplidar_node`. what can i do to let the topic `base_scan` back to `scan`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284494/my-topic-%27scan%27-was-change-to-%27base_scan%27/) by [liu huxian](https://answers.ros.org/users/34017/liu-huxian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-03-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chrissunny94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33207/chrissunny94/) on 2018-03-06**:
you can also edit the rplidar.launch file to change the topic name to suit your need.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-06**:
@chrissunny94 It's not a good idea to edit other packages' source (including launch files). If/when the package is updated then the modified source is gone. @Delb's answer is correct, modify *your own* source, which is under your control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you changed the launch file / rplidar_node? It's normally set to publish on scan.

You can remap the topics with the tag `<remap>` in your launch file :

```
<remap from="base_scan" to="scan"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2018-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [liu huxian](https://answers.ros.org/users/34017/liu-huxian/) on 2018-03-07**:
i haven't changed my the launch file / rplidar_node. but after remap the topics with the tag  in your launch file according to your answer ,i solved my problem, thought i still cannot figureout how this issue happen.thanks a lot for your answering!!